# Error opening tiff in ArcPad

Tags: arcmap, geotiff-tiff, arcpad

I have an ArcPad 10.0 application for which I export tiff images from ArcMap (previously 10.1, now 10.4). The tiff images are created by rasterizing polygon layers. I then set the symbology and export to a new tiff image using the colormap of the tiff.

I generally don’t have a problem with this process, but sometimes when I add a tiff in ArcPad, I get the following message “Error opening …..tif: Error 0”. This happens only with my larger images and when I split the image in two or make the extent smaller, I don’t get the error.

I’ve run a series of processes to see if I can determine exactly what is happening: I’ve made the extent of the image smaller, resampled the image to a bigger cell size, changed the compression  and changed the pixel type from 8 bit to 1 bit (the cell values of the image is only 0 or 1).

What I’ve found is that it seems like the uncompressed size of the tiff has an influence on whether I get the error message or not. Whenever I changed the extent or resampled the image so that the uncompressed size is less than 2GB, I didn’t get the error message. Whether you put compression on the image or not does not seem to make a difference. The weird thing is however that when I change the pixel type to 1 bit I still get the same error message that I get when the uncompressed size of the 8 bit image is 2GB or more, even though the uncompressed size of the 1 bit image is much smaller.

I haven’t found any reference to a size limit for tiff’s in ArcPad. Does anybody know whether a size limit does exist and also why changing to 1 bit image didn’t make a difference? Or is there something else that is causing this problem?